# Can I set the value of an attributes name using xpath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a standard meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="desc" content="test"/>
```

That I want to transform into a new node like this:

```
<xsl:template match="meta">
 <content>
  <xsl:attribute name="test"/>
 </content>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a way to replace 'test' as the attribute name with and xpath expression? Can I use the @name from the meta tag somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to replace 'test' as
>   the attribute name with and xpath
>   expression?

Yes, use a Attribute Value Template like:

**Edit:** To be more clear, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="meta">
        <content>
            <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@content"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<content desc="test" />
```

**Edit:** Following Dimitre's guessing, if you want

```
<content name="desc">test</content>
```

Use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="meta">
        <content name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@content"/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: xsl:value-of @name returns the name of the name. If I change it to name="{@name}" it is null. I tried storing the value in a variable and it works in value-of but not as an expression in the name attribute.

Comment: @Alejandro: It seems that the OP wants `<content name="test>something here</content>`-- not `<content desc="test" /> `

Comment: @Dimitre: Adding your guess, also.